# Excel Max Formula Reference to another cell

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that has been created as a time sheet

Down the left handside (A2 - A50) are the Task Descriptions 
Across the top (B1 - F1) are the days of the week

```
                 Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
Account creation
Pc Setup
Phone Patch
Hardware Swap
```

In the rest of the cells I fill in minutes spent on the tasks

Using the max Formula `=MAX(F2:F50)`, I can find the cell in which I spent the most time on Friday

So for example Cell F3 I spent 55 minutes on a task, so that was the highest for that day

My question is,

Is there a way that I can reference the task description for F3 - so that would be A3 (PC Setup)

As I want to have a cell that is titled:
Task Worked on the Most today:

and for that to display the task description from Column A (A3).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A50,MATCH(MAX(F2:F50),F2:F50,0))
```

Here `MATCH()` formula finds the position of the maximum element in array `F2:F50` and then `INDEX()` formula returns the element having this position from array `A2:A50`.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using VLOOKUP function in excel.
The way to do this is that the max value is passed as the first parameter to the Vlookup function.

Read up on VLOOK up on the internet.

Comment: unfortunately, `VLOOKUP` requires the searched for data to be in column 1, which would not apply in this case

Comment: In a new excel sheet, first column can contain all max values